# Magento 2: Block in Layout not Respecting Cacheable = False

Tags: magento2, layout, caching

I have a block my custom module. The layout file is called                         `davecms_shopping_checkout.xml`.
 Lets assume the module name is davecms and it has a route with a name and id as davecms.

Find below contents of the layout files:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <block class="Gloo\DaveCMS\Block\Checkout" name="gloocms.checkout" template="Gloo_Davecms::checkout.phtml" cacheable="false" />
    </container>
</layout>
```

The page is still being cached. Subsequent calls to the url does not get to the controller, it just displays the .phtml template file. What could be the issue?

Comment: I have the same problem, I have cleared the configuration cache and  flushed storage cache after adding the cacheable attribute for the fist. After that its work for me.

Comment: Have you remove var folder?